# Simple noir server won't start

Tags: clojure, leiningen, noir

I've just started to learn Clojure, and thought a good way to dive into it would be to write a simple Noir website.

I've installed leiningen, did lein self-install and installed the lein noir plugin. When I create a dummy project ...

```
>> lein noir new test-noir
Creating noir project:  test-noir
Creating new dirs at:  /Users/pdeuchler/Documents/workspace/test-noir
Adding files...
Project created!
>> cd test-noir/
```

And then try to run it ...

```
>> lein run
```

I get an error which I googled, but resulted in no relevant results.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core/incubator__init.class or clojure/core/incubator.clj on classpath: , compiling:(response.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3342)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6985)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6975)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7046)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:385)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:425)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
at compojure.core$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3337)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6985)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6975)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7046)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:385)
....
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: That should work. Out of curiosity, what happens when you run lein deps before lein run? Also, what version of Leiningen (lein -v) are you running? And finally what is in your project.clj?

Comment: I get this stack trace when running `lein deps` http://pastebin.com/npSA5rzQ. I'm running Leiningen 1.6.1 on Java 1.6.0_31 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM. This is my `project.clj` (unedited from `lein noir new test-noir`) http://pastebin.com/NfYbH1dh

Comment: Grab the latest stable Leiningen which is at least 1.7.1, and start over. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Updated Leiningen... when running `lein deps` I get what seems to be the same stack trace... http://pastebin.com/8gTQyBx2

Comment: Something is up with Maven and your .m2 directory. This is not a problem with Clojure or lein. Try moving the .m2 directory out of the way and give it another shot.